# image scrolling on touches in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

iam developing an app in which, images are to be scrolled on touchesmove i.e, swipping left /right.

I also have to display previous and next images beside present image in protrait mode.

I have seen the covertFlow sample, which is very close to my app, but i want it in horizontal mode. Please suggest me how can i acheive it , links related to it can also be helpful for me..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my query and it is working without using any libraries.

I used the concept of lazyloading to download images, and i placed the images in scrollview which helps to scroll the images.

The following link used to load images asynchronously.

http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Answer (score 0):

Well how about taking the open source CoverFlow implementation and modify it to work in portrait mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can get sample code in this [tapku Library](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)